# Minimizar un formulario con boton

Tags: vb.net

Tengo una aplicacion de escritorio en VB.NET, es un menu principal donde con un boton llamo a un ABM.

A este ABM le saque los bordes (Y por consiguiente los controles de minimizar, maximizar y cerrar), **para crearle yo una barra para moverlo y botones personalizados para minimizar etc**

En el evento CLICK del boton MINIMIZAR tengo el siguiente codigo

`Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized`

Que segun tengo entendido minimiza el formulario actual. **El problema es que me envia hacia atras de todas las ventanas le menu principal.** Osea, si tengo Chrome y Outlook abiertos me "quita de la pantalla" el menu principal y hay que ir a buscarlo a mano como si estuviese minimizado, cosa que no lo esta, solo esta atras de todo lo que este abierto.

A alguien le paso? O algun otro codigo para minimizar formularios?

Gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! VAmos a necesitar un poco mas de informacion.. Como abriste el nuevo form? donde va a parar el que lo abre, sin que lo minimizes? winform o wpf? Si podes hacer un [mcve] mejor...

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado antes de minimizar utilizar la propiedad TopMost del formulario a minimizar?

```
Me.TopMost = True
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
```

Esto te situaría la ventana por delante de todas...